# Next.js add header element conditional to _document.js

Tags: next.js

I owuld like to add these line to `_document.js` only if a specific route is rendered. Do you know how?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Fintech | Codrop | Landing Page App Template</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<script src="themekit/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="themekit/scripts/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/bootstrap-grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/glide.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/magnific-popup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/content-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/contact-form.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/media-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="skin.css">
<link rel="icon" href="media/favicon.png">
```

_document.js:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main } from "next/document";
import NextScript from "../components/nextscript";
import { FB_PIXEL_ID } from "../lib/fpixel";
import { BARION_PIXEL_ID } from "../lib/barionpixel";
import { NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS } from "../lib/gtm";

class TiketDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/logo.png" />
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo.png" />
          <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
          <meta property="fb:app_id" content="2773133082797983" />
          <meta name="form
```

Comment: Why not simply convert them to JSX and wrap them with [`next/head`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) in your page? For scripts you can also use [`next/script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) component (it needs to be put outside head component).

Comment: Also, you should move meta charSet above link (in _document). w3 specifies that it should be present within first 1024 bytes from the start of file. And, if you are setting it in document, there is no need to set it again in your page. In fact the first 3 meta tags should be moved to document. Others will work just the fine. Not sure of favicon though. It may cause conflict. PS: if you are serving your themekit files through your public folder then you should put a `/` after `href="`.